# "By that time" vs "At that time" with past perfect

Tags: grammaticality

Which sentence seems more accurate -

1. We had already been friends for a while by that time .
2. We had already been friends for a while at that time .

Answer (score 0):

**There is no noticeable difference between the two.**

Both are grammatically correct. Both mean the same thing. Both are in common usage.

Feel free to use whichever you feel like.